# KDB: weighted median

Tags: kdb, median, weighted

How can one compute weighted median in KDB?

I can see that there is a function [med](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/med/) for a simple median but I could not find something like `wmed` similar to [wavg](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/avg/#wavg).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For values `v` and weights `w`, `med v where w` gobbles space for larger values of `w`.

Instead, sort `w` into ascending order of `v` and look for where cumulative sums reach half their sum.

```
q)show v:10?100
17 23 12 66 36 37 44 28 20 30
q)show w:.001*10?1000
0.418 0.126 0.077 0.829 0.503 0.12 0.71 0.506 0.804 0.012
q)med v where "j"$w*1000
36f

q)w iasc v / sort w into ascending order of v
0.077 0.418 0.804 0.126 0.506 0.012 0.503 0.12 0.71 0.829
q)0.5 1*(sum;sums)@\:w iasc v / half the sum and cumulative sums of w
2.0525
0.077 0.495 1.299 1.425 1.931 1.943 2.446 2.566 3.276 4.105
q).[>]0.5 1*(sum;sums)@\:w iasc v / compared
1111110000b
q)v i sum .[>]0.5 1*(sum;sums)@\:w i:iasc v / weighted median
36

q)\ts:1000 med v where "j"$w*1000
18 132192
q)\ts:1000 v i sum .[>]0.5 1*(sum;sums)@\:w i:iasc v
2 2576

q)wmed:{x i sum .[>]0.5 1*(sum;sums)@\:y i:iasc x}
```

Some vector techniques worth noticing:

- Applying two functions with [Each Left](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) `(sum;sums)@\:` and using [Apply](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/) `.` and an operator on the result, rather than setting a variable, e.g. `(0.5*sum yi)>sums yi:y i` or defining an inner lambda `{sums[x]<0.5*sum x}y i`
- Grading one list with [`iasc`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/iasc/) to sort another
- Multiple mappings through juxtaposition: `v i sum ..`

Comment: 1. I would keep the convention of wsum/wavg weights are x,  values are y. 
2. I would use the implicit order of cumulative sums and use binr to find index.
`wmed:{y i sums[x i:iasc y] binr 0.5*sum x}`

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively weight the median by duplicating (using `where`):

```
q)med 10 34 23 123 5 56 where 4 1 1 1 1 1
10f
q)med 10 34 23 123 5 56 where 1 1 1 1 1 4
56f
q)med 10 34 23 123 5 56 where 1 2 1 3 2 1
34f
```

If your weights are percentages (e.g. 0.15 0.10 0.20 0.30 0.25) then convert them to equivalent whole/counting numbers

```
q)med 1 2 3 4 5 where "i"$100*0.15 0.10 0.20 0.30 0.25
4f
```